# Are ngrx/effects monads?

Tags: functional-programming, ngrx, ngrx-effects

We use ngrx/effects to keep our reducers pure. So technically effects are the way of introducing side effects in our application. Does that make effects monads?

Comment: No, introducing side effects while keeping code pure does not make anything a monad.

Answer (score 1):

Monad is essentially a very special kind of much more general structure, named **monoid**. It originates from math and is unbelievable generic (literally, there are no more that 2 simple things came along with some restrictions, satisfying which you get a perfectly valid instance of monoid). This means that your question technically does not make much sense: as long as corresponding implementation meets the above-mentioned requirement (which I did not specify explicitly since it's quite easy to google; in case you need some insight, let me know and I'll share some good links with you), you are fine.

So seems to me like you have to rephrase your initial question such that it becomes more precise and concrete.